# Docker and Nginx resolving to wrong IP addresses

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, dokku

I'm running Dokku 0.9.4 on DigitalOcean to host multiple Node.js application server (apps: `api`, `cms` and `www`). Here is what I do on the fresh droplet installation:

1. Create apps via Dokku: `dokku apps:create {app-name}`
2. Initialize GIT respositories on my development machine and successfully deploy all 3 apps to the server

At this moment applications work until I restart server or execute `service docker restart`. After any of these two happen problems start to arise. First, applications are not accessible for a minute or two at all (when I try to access any of these apps via `{app-name}.domain.tld` I'm getting `502 Bad gateway` (DNS handled by Cloudflare). Then if it decides to start working after few minutes app mapping seems to be mixed up.

For example, if I try to open `www.domain.tld` I'm actually getting response from `api` application while at the same time opening `cms.domain.tld` returns `502 Bad gateway`.

After spending the whole day yesterday trying to pinpoint the problem I've just now managed to find the location of the problem but I don't understand why it happens.

Running `docker networks inspect bridge` gives the following result:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "e9edc54047f3d93b9033706d17fd78355440470a090c8010577cfca6ef767946",
        "Created": "2017-12-12T09:16:52.784428035Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "Containers": {
            "28d7242a146a160dafc94b325439b6385bd49155dec9124e501daf88f8744740": {
                "Name": "www.web.1",
                "EndpointID": "26f276f07c983755f0baab9999292b23445d4cdf060328e9e1e3cd8914326310",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "32b2a15f8ccaff48e46f707bb9619d7d106fb18a0632483cc6db341d24d5b606": {
                "Name": "cms.web.1",
                "EndpointID": "a605bab5af1ec76c802537953b1869116d0ade37bdecf2f76c33c1592ee25b01",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "500bd73a805ef63d9b2eb4589b3abe4316b72f2d7e029d2dfc71886c6f6fc807": {
                "Name": "api.web.1",
                "EndpointID": "cd5f8ebd7f2c6dfc8b5828eed1f0a46336415ba8204f9b58270b18ae42aaf357",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.8/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

However, if I check each app's `nginx.conf` inside `/home/dokku/{app-name}/nginx.conf` I can see where the problem is. For example, app `api` has the following `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name api.tourlyapp.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/api-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/api-error.log;

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://api-5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  include /home/dokku/api/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

}

upstream api-5000 {

  server 172.17.0.5:5000;
}
```

while app `www` has the following `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name www.tourlyapp.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/www-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/www-error.log;

  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://www-5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  include /home/dokku/www/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 420 422 423 424 426 428 429 431 444 449 450 451 /400-error.html;
  location /400-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 404 /404-error.html;
  location /404-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 /500-error.html;
  location /500-error.html {
    root /var/lib/dokku/data/nginx-vhosts/dokku-errors;
    internal;
  }

}

upstream www-5000 {

  server 172.17.0.8:5000;
}
```

Apart from the fact that for some reason unknown to me `www` app has more entries inside `nginx.conf` than `api` app, it also shows that IPs are mixed up:

`www` app has upstream IP address set to `172.17.0.8` while this IP address is assigned by Docker to `api` app.
`api` app has upstream IP address set to `172.17.0.8` and it is the same IP addressed assigned to it by Docker

No matter what I do, IP addresses are still messed up (I've tried `dokku nginx:build-config www`, I've tried making the most simple Node.js apps and the problem persists, I've tried fresh droplet installation etc.).

The only thing that makes all apps work correctly is running `dokku ps:restart {app-name}`. This magically make it work until next server reboot.

Is there anyone who knows what the hell is wrong because I've wasted really too much time trying to fix things that should be working out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appears to be updating Dokku to version `0.11.0` where new plugin `network` is added which, among other things, rebuilds IP addresses after Docker service gets restarted.

Related issues:

- https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/2085
- https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/2403